# Handling sub query which retrieves large amount of data

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery, oracle12c

I am using this query:

```
select test.* from 
(
SELECT /*+ full(P) parallel(a,24) */
a.TRANS_DATE,a.STORE_NO,a.POS_NO,a.TICKET_NO,a.TICKET_START_TIME, a.INTERNAL_NO,
a.TRANS_DATE||a.STORE_NO||a.POS_NO||a.TICKET_NO||a.TICKET_START_TIME as VISITS,
s.city,s.region,
a.CUSTOMER_NO,
a.GROSS_AMT,
a.SALE_QTY,
a.DISCOUNT_AMT,
a.DISCOUNT_QTY,
S.FORMAT_CD,
S.FORMAT_DESC,
P.BRAND_ID,
P.BRAND_ID_DESC,
P.BRAND_TYPE,
P.BRAND_TYPE_DESC,
P.LEVEL1,P.LEVEL1_DESC,P.LEVEL2,
P.LEVEL2_DESC,P.LEVEL3,P.LEVEL3_DESC,P.LEVEL4,
P.LEVEL4_DESC,P.LEVEL5,P.LEVEL5_DESC,
P.Material_No,P.Medium_Desc,
b.mobile,
D.MOBILE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.TRANS_DATE,a.STORE_NO,a.POS_NO,a.TICKET_NO,a.TICKET_START_TIME, a.INTERNAL_NO,
                                s.city,s.region,a.CUSTOMER_NO,a.GROSS_AMT,a.SALE_QTY,a.DISCOUNT_AMT,a.DISCOUNT_QTY,
                                S.FORMAT_CD,S.FORMAT_DESC,P.BRAND_ID,P.BRAND_ID_DESC,P.BRAND_TYPE,P.BRAND_TYPE_DESC,
                                P.LEVEL1,P.LEVEL1_DESC,P.LEVEL2,P.LEVEL2_DESC,P.LEVEL3,P.LEVEL3_DESC,P.LEVEL4,P.LEVEL4_DESC,
                                P.LEVEL5,P.LEVEL5_DESC,P.Material_No,P.Medium_Desc,b.mobile
                                ORDER BY D.MOBILE) as rnk
FROM  P
INNER JOIN  a ON a.Internal_No= P.Material_No
INNER JOIN  S ON TO_CHAR(a.STORE_NO)= S.STORE_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN  b ON a.store_no=b.store_no and a.ticket_no=b.ticket_no and a.trans_date=b.trans_date
                                    and a.ticket_start_time=b.ticket_start_time and a.pos_no=b.pos_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN  d ON a.customer_no=d.customer_no                                    
where  a.TRANS_DATE between '07/04/2014' and sysdate
)test
where test.rnk=1
```

Problem with this query is, subquery is retriving large amount of rows and every time I run this query I am getting below error -

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP1.
```

How can I handle this without increasing TEMP tablespace.

Best Regards

Comment: What are you using table `b` for?

Comment: sorry, edited the code

Comment: Did you think about putting the subquery into a view instead? Or - depending on how often the data is changed - a Snapshot? Might be worth a try to create a Snapshot and then refresh the Snapshot from time to time...